# How to call msys2 find command from PowerShell with correct shell escape characters?

Tags: powershell, msys2

I'm wondering how can I escape the following command from PowerShell so that it works?

```
PS C:\Users\buster\Documents\> find -name \*.c
```

PowerShell says: error not found *.c

```
PS C:\Users\buster\Documents\> find -name *.c
```

PowerShell says: error not found *.c

Answer (score 1):

If you used `find` like that (without the full path) you most likely used the [`find.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655.aspx) that ships with Windows (`C:\Windows\system32\find.exe`), which is more akin to `grep` than to Unix `find`. You get that behavior because Windows searches all directories in `$env:PATH` for files with the given name (and one of the extensions listed in `$env:PATHEXT` if no extension was specified), and executes the first match. Since `%windir%\system32` is usually at the beginning of the PATH, executables from there take precedence.

You could add `C:\msys64\msys64\usr\bin` to the beginning of the PATH (before `%windir%\system32`), although I wouldn't recommend that. A better way would be to define an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-3.0) for the command:

```
New-Alias -Name 'find' -Value 'C:\msys64\msys64\usr\bin\find.exe'
```

Aliases take precedence over files. You could put the alias definition in your PowerShell [profile](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) so that it's automatically loaded whenever you start PowerShell.

Or you could simply use `ls -r -fi '*.c'` (short for `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.c'`), which would be the PowerShell way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok false alarm..

Apparently its a case of windows having an executable with the same name as msys2's find.exe under c:\windows\system32 and the windows command getting higher priority in the path list.  After explicitly typing out the full path to the msys64 version of find.exe it works.

```
PS C:\Users\buster\Documents\> C:\msys64\msys64\usr\bin\find -name \*.c
```

Also, Turns out there's a better way to find *.c files native to cmd.exe that you can call from powershell like this:

```
PS C:\Users\buster\Documents\> cmd /c dir /S /B *.v
```